# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider: itemslistProvider <-

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-services

I have been debugging the code for around several days but unable to find the solution. I have read the angularjs documentation as well as several existing SO questions for the error but still unable to spot any of the error due to which the code is failing.

This is one of my assignment which I have almost completed and written the code for it but I am just stuck in displaying the items in a category. The code for displaying the category is working fine but the very similar code for displaying the item is not. I am really confused and hit a dead end. I request you to only give me a hint or a line where I may be going wrong. I am not requesting the whole solution because it is against the honor code.

So, here are the files

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <title>My Restro</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="MenuApp">
<ui-view></ui-view>

<!-- Libraries -->
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Modules -->
 <script src="src/menuapp/menuapp.module.js"></script>
 <script src="src/menuapp/data.module.js"></script>
 <!-- Routes -->
 <script src="src/routes.js"></script>

 <!-- 'MenuApp' module artifacts -->
 <script src="src/menuapp/menudata.service.js"></script>
 <script src="src/menuapp/categories.component.js"></script>
 <script src="src/menuapp/categories.controller.js"></script>
 <script src="src/menuapp/items.component.js"></script>
 <script src="src/menuapp/item-detail.controller.js"></script>
 <!-- <script src="src/menuapp/main-menuapp.controller.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

item-detail.controller:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('MenuApp')
  .controller('ItemDetailController', ItemDetailController);

  // 'itemlist' is injected through state's resolve
  ItemDetailController.$inject = ['MenuDataService','itemslist'];
  function ItemDetailController(MenuDataService,itemslist) {
    var itemDetailCtrl = this;
    itemDetailCtrl.itemslist=itemslist;
   }

   })();
```

routes.js

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

  angular.module('MenuApp')
  .config(RoutesConfig);

   RoutesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
   function RoutesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  .........//other states code.....
  //items state code
  .state('items', {
    url: '/items/{categoryShortName}',
    templateUrl: 'src/menuapp/templates/item-detail.template.html',
    controller: 'ItemDetailController as itemDetailCtrl',
    resolve: {
        itemlist: ['$stateParams', 'MenuDataService',
        function ($stateParams, MenuDataService) {
          return MenuDataService.getItemsForCategories($stateParams.categoryShortName);
        }]
    }
  });
 }

 })();
```

Comment: post your code for itemslist factory

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have edit the question. I think that is what you want. However you can still access the whole app at the given url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route you have resolve name  itemlist and you injecting it as itemslist. Ii should be like this.

```
ItemDetailController.$inject = ['MenuDataService','itemlist'];
function ItemDetailController(MenuDataService,itemlist) {
  var itemDetailCtrl = this;
  itemDetailCtrl.itemlist=itemlist;
}
```

})();

Comment: It is so funny as well as embarrassing to do such mistakes (: I think I should punish myself over this. However, thank you for your help.